# What exist libraries for transform your configuration data into an Erlang source

Tags: configuration, erlang

To have configuration data in native erlang source is not very useful - it creates difficulties in automatic generation of config and further distribution of project.

One of the approach is to transform your configuration data into an Erlang source module that makes the configuration data available through exports.

What exist libraries to do it. I found only [cuttlefish](https://github.com/basho/cuttlefish) unfortunately is not supported R17 yet.

Comment: Consider giving a more specific example of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can format the configuration data as Erlang tuples and then use [file:consult/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#consult-1).

Comment: In this case not exist of opportunity to validate the configuration file except running  the application. Considering that tools for deployment can be based not on Erlang this is no very good choise. Also for possibility of assigning default value need to write additional codeand i would like to take the ready solution.